# SharePoint App to Insert Record in Host Web List using REST API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have written the following code to insert records in a list which is contained in the host site.

```
var projectItems = [
    { Title: "SharePoint", ProjectDescription: "SharePoint 2013", ProjectManager: "Test0" },
    { Title: "Lync", ProjectDescription: "Lync 2013", ProjectManager: "Test1" },
    { Title: "Exchange", ProjectDescription: "Exchange 2013", ProjectManager: "Test2" }
];

function insertListItems(items) {
    for (var item in items) {

        var inputData = new Object();
        var type = new Object();
        type.type = getListItemType(listName);
        inputData.__metadata = type;
        for (var prop in items[item]) {
            inputData[prop] = items[item][prop];
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(inputData));
        console.log(url);

        var obj = {
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
            success: function (successData) { console.log("insert successful"); },
            error: function (errorData) { console.log("insert failed") }
        };

        if (parent) {
            var exec = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);
            exec.executeAsync(obj);

        } else {
            $.ajax(obj);
        }            
    }
}

insertListItems(projectItems);
```

when I run it it prints

{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.ProjectsListItem"},"Title":"SharePoint","ProjectDescription":"SharePoint 2013","ProjectManager":"Test0"}

http://app-e9f4c136adfd88.abhiapps.com/SPAppHelper/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?@target='http://dev.abhi.com'

{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.ProjectsListItem"},"Title":"Lync","ProjectDescription":"Lync 2013","ProjectManager":"Test1"}

http://app-e9f4c136adfd88.abhiapps.com/SPAppHelper/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?@target='http://dev.abhi.com'

{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.ProjectsListItem"},"Title":"Exchange","ProjectDescription":"Exchange 2013","ProjectManager":"Test2"}

http://app-e9f4c136adfd88.abhiapps.com/SPAppHelper/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?@target='http://dev.abhi.com'

insert successful 
 insert successful 
 insert successful

I have multiple problems with this source code

1. No records actually get inserted. but no errors are thrown.
2. How do I ensure that in my main method... the code which comes after the insertListItems method is only executed when all the 3 records have been inserted successfully. currently because of the async nature of javascript the flow moves forward even before anything has been inserted.
3. I googled on option 2 and found that jquery has a promise and deffered object pattern but it seems SP.RequestExecutor.executeAsync does not follow that and throws an error on the "done" method saying no such method is supported.

This is how my lists looks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your obj with this:

```
        ....
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        headers: {
                 "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
             }
        ....
        ....
```